# PyOpenGL: glutTimerFunc callback missing required param 'value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

Using PyOpenGL, I am trying to create a simple triangle that changes colour on every refresh call and I'm trying to use glutTimerFunc(...) to do this.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import random

def display(value):
    v1 = [-.25,0]
    v2 = [0,.25]
    v3 = [.25, 0]
    r = random.randint(0,255)
    g = random.randint(0,255)
    b = random.randint(0,255)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)

    glColor3b(r,g,b)
    glVertex2f(v1[0], v1[1])
    glVertex2f(v2[0], v2[1])
    glVertex2f(v3[0], v3[1])

    glEnd()
    glFlush()

    glutTimerFunc(1000, display, 5)
    glutPostRedisplay()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500)
    glutCreateWindow("First Shape")
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutMainLoop()
```

This is the error I am getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 232, in 'calling callback function'
TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

I have tried passing 'value' and placing it in the parameter list for display() with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function required by [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) has no paramter, but the callback function required by [`glutTimerFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) has on parameter. So you can't use the same function for both.
Something like the following would be possibe:

```
def timer(value):
    display()

def display()

    glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 5)
```

But that wont solve your issue, because 
[`glutPostRedisplay`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html)  marks the current window as needing to be redisplayed and causes that the display callback function, which is set by [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html), is called.

If you want to change the color by time, then create a timer function, which sets a new color and restarts the timer:

```
r = 255
g = 255
b = 255

def timer(value):
    global r, b, g
    r = random.randint(0,255)
    g = random.randint(0,255)
    b = random.randint(0,255)
    glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 5)
```

Remove the timer initialization form the `display` function

```
def display():
    global r, b, g
    v1 = [-.25,0]
    v2 = [0,.25]
    v3 = [.25, 0]
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)

    glColor3b(r,g,b)
    glVertex2f(v1[0], v1[1])
    glVertex2f(v2[0], v2[1])
    glVertex2f(v3[0], v3[1])

    glEnd()
    glFlush()

    glutPostRedisplay()
```

But call the `timer` function once at startup:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500)
    glutCreateWindow("First Shape")
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    timer(0);
    glutMainLoop()
```